# HTTP Get request | Long wait time

Tags: performance, apache, http

I have a web site, that is speed optimized, and work well, but the last week I have find an issue for the very first request that is strange to me.

The first request I am creating takes a long time to be executed. In the "Network" tab of my Chrome I have experienced the following:

[image]

Can somebody explain me what that could be ? So, what's the reason I am getting so long wait time ? Is it posible to "debug" somehow this wait time ?

**NOTE :** The web site is running on dedicated 8core web server, and is the only one web site on this server. The server is based on LAMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to check these things :

- Load of the server
- Load of Apache HTTPd (is it overloaded of queries? When the maximum is reached, subsequent requests become slow)
- Load of the database and/or slow queries

All of this depends on what this URL is doing behind. Without knowing it, can't help much.

Comment: Thansk for your response, so you beleave I have to test my script load and response speed. Kind regards ...

Comment: @MerianosNikos I think it mostly depends on your theme's category template, you can try to strip everything inside to isolate the problem (server / code) after add parts by parts to know if it is related with slow query or bad coding... etc.